# Why is a query under a IF statement that is false running?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a application that uses a lot of string interpolation for SQL queries.  I know it is a SQL injection threat, this is something that the customer and us know about and is hopefully something we can focus on next big refactor.  I say that to make sense of the `{Root Container.property}` things that come from a GUI.

I have this query

```
IF ({Root Container.UserSelectedProduct}=1)
    begin
        DECLARE @TestNumbers {Root Container.SQLProductType};
        INSERT INTO @TestNumbers SELECT * FROM {Root Container.DBTable};
        SELECT *
        FROM {Root Container.SQLProductFunction} (@TestNumbers)
        WHERE [ID] = {Root Container.Level};
    end
else
    Select 0
```

Before a user selects a product it looks like this

```
IF (0=1)     
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @TestNumbers myDataType;
    INSERT INTO @TestNumbers SELECT * FROM [MySchema].[TheWrongTable];     
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[myfunction] (@TestNumbers)
    WHERE [ID] = 1;
  END
ELSE
  SELECT 0
```

Which is giving me the error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I am aware why this error shows up, the table I am selecting from is not made for that data type.

However, why is it even attempting to run the first IF clause when I have `IF (0=1)` - how come this part is not just skipped and the `SELECT 0` is only run?  I would have thought that is how it was supposed to work, but I keep getting the error regarding column name/number not matching the table definition.  When the user does select a Product and I get `IF (1=1)` and I have the appropriate table/function/datatype, it all works smoothly. I just don't know why it throws me an error prior when IF(1=0).  Why does this happen/how can I get my intended behavior that everything inside my `BEGIN\END` under my first IF statement does not run unless the expression is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T-SQL is not interpreted. It must make sense regardless of what the runtime conditions are. It doesn't even do short-circuiting, in fact. Your code is invalid, and it doesn't matter that it's unreachable - T-SQL isn't going to ignore a piece of invalid code just because it could be eliminated, that's a thing that is a common source of bugs (e.g. in C++ where it's pretty common with templates).

Just make sure you still get valid SQL for the case where no product is selected; use the wrong table (or a helper table) if you have to.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is simple:** SQL code is fully compiled by the server *before* being executed, so this is basically a compile error. It's a bit like trying to compile the following in C#

```cs
if(someBoolWhichIsFalse)
    intValue = "hello";
```

It's simply not valid.

The runtime code has not even been executed, it's still in the parsing and lexing stage. Nothing is being skipped, it just needs to be fully valid code, irrespective of runtime conditions.

This happens in every scope, i.e. on every call to a procedure or ad-hoc batch, that code must be compilable.